# shopify pass a variable to settings

Tags: shopify, liquid

i want to do something like this in Shopify:

```
{% for i in (0..10) %}
  {% capture slide %}slide{{i}}{% endcapture %}
  {{ settings.slide }}//i need the value of this one
  // i want to get the values for settings.slide1, settings.slide2 etc
{% endfor %}
```

Another example:

```
{% for i in (0..10) %}
  {{ settings.slide[i] }}//i need the value of this one
{% endfor %}
```

This is a simplified version of what im trying to achieve.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for i in (0..10) %}
  {% assign current_slide = 'slide' | append: i %}
  {{ settings[current_slide] }}
{% endfor %}
```